# State-change verbs are mostly in perfect tense?

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-aspect

I know one of the uses of the perfect tense is to describe an action from the past that influences the present.

Then I would expect most of *state change* (changed, grew, transformed, moved) verbs to be used in perfect tense mainly.

However Google search shows the [opposite](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20changed%20%2Che%20has%20changed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20changed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20has%20changed%3B%2Cc0). What am I missing?

Comment: "inflates"  can you check this word  What do you mean by "inflates the present"?

Comment: Fixed the typo: influences

Comment: I think what you're missing is that the perfect is far more complex than that - [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/9161) from [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/9161) might help.